# Ruby - Find Tag by ID

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm using mechanize and nokogiri.  I'm trying to find this tag.  When I inspect the HTML it looks like this.

```
<table class="matchupBox" id="MLB_5_block ">
```

When I print it out in my console it looks like this

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2cc1a1c name="table" attributes=[
#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2cc1940 name="class" value="matchupBox">,
 #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2cc192c name="id" value="MLB_5_block\r\n            ">]
```

I am using this code.

```
doc.search("table#MLB_5_block")
```

but it doesn't match.  Whereas this does match

```
doc.search("table.matchupBox")
```

so I think the problem has to do with that "\r\n  " white space the site is adding.  How do I match it, using the id, and without being dependent on that whitespace?

Comment: What if you do `doc.css('table#MLB_5_block')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to do :

```
doc.search("//table[normalize-space(@id) = 'MLB_5_block']")
```

> The [`normalize-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

Comment: i made a minor change to the syntax and it works, doc.search("//table[normalize-space(@id) = 'MLB_5_block']")